# How do I deal with metagaming/power-playing as a player?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, problem-players, problem-gm, powergaming

I'm in a D&D Homebrew campaign that allows pretty much anything as long as it is written online. We have one player in specific who is frustrating and decided at the end of the campaign, he would try to kill us all off.

The reason for this is his race and class. They happen to be a Terminator t-800, and this would not be a problem if it were not for the fact that whomever who wrote it decided they get an insta-kill and stop time.

I am much faster than him, but because of the DM, he has a 20 AC.

The DM is a pretty cool guy, but he says that me and the 15 people I asked about the character being op are wrong, and I need to stop complaining, or I will be killed off. I only have one person in the campaign who I know will help me, but they keep threatening me to not team up with him, or else, because they think I invited him to help me, even though this became a problem afterwards.

The DM is kinda like a sugar daddy to him, and will just give him what he asks for. When I pointed out that multi classing into hamon user can give me infinite spin, they got scared, and started pulling some **.

I also don't know he is not human yet, so I have to find that out somehow before I attempt anything.

TL;DR: Another player is overpowered and I can't deal with him because plot armor.

I probably should have mentioned this to begin with, I want to know how to beat them in-game, because talking just never seems to work with these people. Also, the anything goes part is kinda exaggerated, because he won't let you have universe destroying powers. I don't necessarily want to beat them in a fight, I just want to avoid my character dying, so it doesn't have to end with me teaming with the boss.

So basically, I want a scheme to keep my character alive.

Comment: We're gonna need you to be specific about which edition of D&D you're playing here - you probably want the [tag:dnd-5e] tag. (Though honestly, in a game where the DM allows any random homebrew you can find on the internet, the normal rules of D&D probably don't have much relevance to your problems.)

Comment: Are you asking how to deal with this *in-game* or *out-of-game*? If you're asking how to deal with this in-game then I don't know that we'll be able to answer it considering it's a "homebrew campaign that allows pretty much anything as long as it is written online*. We don't know the full extent of the homebrew'd rules, classes, races, powers, spells, equipment, etc. and considering "I can't deal with him because plot armor" it seems like there's no answer we can give you anyway. If you're asking about how to deal with this out-of-game then you'll need to clarify that.

Comment: Could you add some details about table composition? How many players are there? Are they negatively affected by this player or are you on your own here?

Comment: Related: [What do I do about a selfish and controlling player (the DM's best friend)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94635/52137) and [A player in my game is using homebrew to powergame; how can I stop this? \[closed\]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/146978/52137)

Comment: But where are our manners, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Ok, I fixed a bit, can we reopen the question?

Comment: *"but they keep **threatening** me to not team up with him, **or else**, because they think I invited him to help me, even though this became a problem afterwards."* WTF? Maybe I misinterpret what you write here, but that sounds rather bad, on any table, and a reason to walk... no, to run away.

Answer (score 1):

## Have an honest conversation about how the game is making you feel

A significant amount of conflict when dealing with group dynamics is resolved through communication and understanding. Take an honest look at the game and whether or not you are having fun playing. If you are not, which it certainly sounds that way, then express to the DM and the group that you are not having fun so that you can all work as a group to incorporate your needs as a player.

At the end of the day, people play games to have fun. Now, to the T-800, their idea of fun may very well be wrecking other players. There isn't anything inherently wrong with that; there are games for that sort of play. However, TTRPGs are social games, and successful TTRPG games are ones in which everyone, including the DM, is having fun.

Be prepared to hear other players' needs during this conversation, including the T-800. Be prepared to point out that the DM is appearing to cater to the T-800 in an unfair manner. There is a possibility that the DM, or one or more of the other players, may not be willing to alter aspects of the game to incorporate your needs to have fun. If this is the case, you need to be prepared to accept that this particular group or game is not right for you.

If you start the conversation with an open mind, and the group as a whole has the same goal of making sure *everyone* is having fun, you should be able to work out a way to continue without anyone having to leave the table.